# Undefined Behavior on inner realloc()

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I'm attempting to write a PE parser, and my program contains two loops as shown below:

```
    size_t i = 0;
    while (condition_1) {
        struct _IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR64 *importDescriptorArray = malloc(sizeof(struct _IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR64));

        struct _IMAGE_THUNK_DATA64 *originalFirstThunkArray = malloc(sizeof(struct _IMAGE_THUNK_DATA64));

        size_t originalFirstThunkArrayIndex = 0;

        originalFirstThunkArray[originalFirstThunkArrayIndex].u1.ordinal = some_value; //set to a computed value

        while (condition_2) {
            originalFirstThunkArrayIndex++;

            originalFirstThunkArray = realloc(originalFirstThunkArray, originalFirstThunkArrayIndex * sizeof(struct _IMAGE_THUNK_DATA64));

            originalFirstThunkArrayOffset += sizeof(QWORD); //each element has its address stored as a QWORD, so I have to iterate QWORD-at-a-time.
            originalFirstThunkArray[originalFirstThunkArrayIndex].u1.ordinal = reverse_endianess_u_int64_t(readQWord(file, originalFirstThunkArrayOffset, QWORD_Buffer));
        }

        i++;
        importDescriptorArray = realloc(importDescriptorArray, i * sizeof(struct _IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR64));
    }
```

I can execute the outer loop `n` number of times and it will always give me the correct output. The *inner* loop however, randomly gives me correct answers or exits via a `malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object` error message.

My codebase is beyond copy/pasting, but here are the definitions of the structures:

```
struct _IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR64 {
    union {
        DWORD Characteristics;
        IMAGE_THUNK_DATA32 OriginalFirstThunk;
    } u;
    DWORD timeDateStamp;
    DWORD forwarderChain;
    DWORD name;
    IMAGE_THUNK_DATA32 FirstThunk;
} IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR64;

typedef struct _IMAGE_THUNK_DATA64 {
    union {
        QWORD forwarderString;
        QWORD function;
        QWORD ordinal;
        QWORD addressOfData;
    } u1;
} IMAGE_THUNK_DATA64;
```

I've narrowed down the line causing the error to the `realloc()` function of the inner loop, but I fail to understand why - is it because I'm accessing the array immediately after reallocation (but I am changing the index so that I edit data of the newly allocated space and not something else)?

What I am trying to do is allocate a single struct at a time (in order to conserve memory) because unless the structures are read until a certain condition is met, there is no other way to know how many of them exist.

Comment: Okay, I'm an idiot. I initialized with zero, incremented and then accessed out-of-bounds. This issue can be fixed by simply changing the index values of the realloc to (index+1) as so:

originalFirstThunkArray = realloc(originalFirstThunkArray, (originalFirstThunkArrayIndex+1)*sizeof(struct _IMAGE_THUNK_DATA64));

importDescriptorArray = realloc(importDescriptorArray, (i+1)*sizeof(struct _IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR64));

Comment: Using simple, readable `for` loops in the form `for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)` tend to auto-magically fix a lot of bugs like that.

Comment: Note that the idiom `old_data = realloc(old_data, new_size);` is an incipient memory leak. If the reallocation fails, you can no longer access the old data. Use `void *new_data = realloc(old_data, new_size); if (new_data == NULL) { …deal with error… } old_data = new_data; old_size = new_size;` or thereabouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`originalFirstThunkArrayIndex` is the index to the last element of the array, not the length of the array. You should reallocate with one extra element in the loop:

```
    originalFirstThunkArray = realloc(originalFirstThunkArray,
                                      (originalFirstThunkArrayIndex + 1) *
                                      sizeof(struct _IMAGE_THUNK_DATA64));
```

Note that your identifiers are very long, making the code hard to read.

There is a similar problem for `i` and `importDescriptorArray`...

Finally a more important problem: `importDescriptorArray` is defined locally in the outer `while` loop body, so its value is lost at each iteration.

Comment: Yep, thank you, I think we realized the index error at the same time! And I've mistakenly put `importDescriptorArray` inside of the outer while loop  - apologies for the copy/paste error - this is most likely, as you have stated correctly, due to poor naming practices on my end. Lesson learnt!